# Equivalent of sql's SUM & GROUP BY on R data.table/data.frame?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Suppose I have the following `data.frame`/`data.table` object:

```
foo <- data.frame(sku = c('123','234','567'), shipped_units_wk1 = c(20,10,10), shipped_units_wk2 = c(25,25,50), category = c("AA", "AA", "BB"))

sku     shipped_units_wk1    shipped_units_wk2   category
123     20                   25                  AA
234     10                   25                  AA
567     10                   50                  BB
```

I need it in the following format:

```
category    shipped_units_wk1    shipped_units_wk2
AA          30                   50
BB          10                   50
```

I can use the `sqldf` package to accomplish this, but is there a faster method in a different package for this? My actual `data.frame` has tens of thousands of rows & 20 columns.

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping The relevant one for your case looks like `lapply(.SD, sum) ...`

Comment: @Gregor I'm switching the dupe to the one for multiple vars.